# Python: format service now exports of Incidents data specially work notes column to determine Incident breach or not breach status

Tags: servicenow

I am very new to Python development.

Currently I have task in my mind which I want to automate using Python.

I have monthly data of Incidents, Our team had to open each incident manually and track when incident   was assigned to teams service now queue, how much time team had taken to solve incidents, Was incident in pending after it had been assigned to service now queue and then calculate SLA of Incident.

All above information is available worknotes field of Incident but when data is exported and  read through python pandas, work notes field output is weird.( it comes with Html tags of Line break)

Does anyone know how to format data from dataframe column or to get correct out put from Service now dump.
I do not have any APIs access to service now. I am relying on ServiceNow export options, which are available in excel, csv and Jason format.

Any help on this topic is appreciated..